# EntityMetadataNotFoundError on Jest while using Typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jestjs, typeorm

I've been trying to get look for this problem for over 2 days now. I don't know if there's an implementation error. Ok here we go, I want to test my API routes in jest and I currently have only 2 API's register and login. Here's how my files look like.

**src/data-source.ts**

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '@src/entities/User';
import 'reflect-metadata';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'users',
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [User],
    migrationsRun: true,
    migrations: ['@src/migrations/*'],
});

export const TestDataSource = new DataSource({
    name: 'test',
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5433,
    username: 'test',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'tests',
    dropSchema: true,
    synchronize: true,
    entities: ["@src/entities/*.ts"],
});
```

**src/services/user.service.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { User } from '@src/entities/User';
import { validateUserInput } from '@src/utils/validateUserInput';
import argon2 from 'argon2';
import { AppDataSource } from '@src/data-source';
import { EntityManager, QueryFailedError, Repository } from 'typeorm';
export interface UserInputParameters {
    name: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
export interface UserResponse {
    user?: User;
    errors?: FieldError[];
}
export interface SecureUserResponse {
    user?: {
        name: string;
        email: string;
        username: string;
    };
    errors?: FieldError[];
}

export interface FieldError {
    field: string;
    message: string;
}

export const queryFailedGuard = (err: unknown): err is QueryFailedError & { code: string } =>
    err instanceof QueryFailedError;

const UserRepository: Repository<User> = AppDataSource.getRepository(User);

export const registerService = async (inputParameters: UserInputParameters): Promise<UserResponse> => {
    const errors = validateUserInput(inputParameters);
    if (errors) {
        return { errors };
    }
    const { name, username, email, password } = inputParameters;
    const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(password);
    let user = new User();
    try {
        UserRepository.merge(user,{
            name,
            username,
            email,
            password: hashedPassword,
        })
        await UserRepository.save(user);
    } catch (err) {
        if (queryFailedGuard(err)) {
            if (err.code === '23505') {
                console.log(err);
                return {
                    errors: [
                        {
                            field: 'username',
                            message: 'Username already exists',
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'email',
                            message: 'Email already exists',
                        },
                    ],
                };
            }
        }
    }

    return { user };
};

export const loginService = async (usernameOrEmail: string, password: string): Promise<SecureUserResponse> => {
    let user;
    try {
        user = await UserRepository.findOneBy(
            usernameOrEmail.includes('@') ? { email: usernameOrEmail } : { username: usernameOrEmail }
        );
        console.log(user);
        if (!user) {
            return {
                errors: [
                    {
                        field: 'usernameOrEmail',
                        message: 'Invalid Username or Email',
                    },
                ],
            };
        }
        const valid = await argon2.verify(user.password, password);
        if (!valid) {
            return {
                errors: [
                    {
                        field: 'password',
                        message: 'Invalid password',
                    },
                ],
            };
        }
        return {
            user: {
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                name: user.name,
            },
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return {
            errors: [
                {
                    field: 'usernameOrEmail',
                    message: 'Error in logging in',
                },
            ],
        };
    }
};

//@TODO: update user, forget password, deleteAccount, view tasks.
```

**src/**tests**/user.test.ts**

```
import { createServer } from '@src/config/createServer';
import { testConnection } from '@src/utils/connections';
import supertest from 'supertest';
let app = createServer();
beforeAll(async () => {
    await testConnection.create();
    // server = await app.listen(4000);
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await testConnection.close();
    // server.close();
});
let registeredUser = {
    usernameOrEmail: 'shravan26',
    password: 'shravan98',
};
let testUser = {
    name: 'shravan',
    username: 'shravan26',
    email: 'shravan@gmail.com',
    password: 'shravan98',
};
describe('POST /register', () => {
    it('should register user if all fields exist', async () => {
        let testUser = {
            name: 'shravan',
            username: 'shravan26',
            email: 'shravan@gmail.com',
            password: 'shravan98',
        };
        const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/register').send(testUser);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body.message).toBe('Successfully registered user');
    });
    it('should throw error if email field is missing', async () => {
        let testUser = {
            name: 'shravan',
            username: 'shravan26',
            email: 'email',
            password: 'shravan98',
        };

        const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/register').send(testUser);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(401);
        expect(response.body[0].field).toBe('email');
        expect(response.body[0].message).toBe('Please enter a valid email');
    });
    it('should throw error if email is invalid', async () => {
        let testUser = {
            name: 'shravan',
            username: 'shravan26',
            email: '@',
            password: 'shravan98',
        };
        const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/register').send(testUser);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(401);
        expect(response.body[0].field).toBe('email');
        expect(response.body[0].message).toBe('Please enter a valid email');
    });
    it('should throw error if name is empty', async () => {
        let testUser = {
            name: '',
            username: 'shravan26',
            email: 'shravan@gmail.com',
            password: 'shravan98',
        };
        const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/register').send(testUser);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(401);
        expect(response.body[0].field).toBe('name');
        expect(response.body[0].message).toBe('Please enter a valid name');
    });
    it('should throw error if username is less than 4 characters', async () => {
        let testUser = {
            name: 'shravan',
            username: '',
            email: 'shravan@gmail.com',
            password: 'shravan98',
        };
        const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/register').send(testUser);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(401);
        expect(response.body[0].field).toBe('username');
        expect(response.body[0].message).toBe('Username should be more than 4 characters');
    });
    it('should throw error if password is less than 8 characters', async () => {
        let testUser = {
            name: 'shravan',
            username: 'shravan26',
            email: 'shravan@gmail.com',
            password: 'shr',
        };
        const response = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/register').send(testUser);
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(401);
        expect(response.body[0].field).toBe('password');
        expect(response.body[0].message).toBe('Password should be more than 8 characters');
    });
    it('should login a registered user', async () => {
        const loginResponse = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/login').send(registeredUser);
        console.log(loginResponse);
        expect(loginResponse.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

When i run this on nodemon, my API routes are working,
But when i call jest, only my login fails and gives me EntityMetadataNotFoundError like this:

**Console**

```
  EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.
        at DataSource.getMetadata (/Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:423:30)
        at Repository.get metadata [as metadata] (/Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/repository/Repository.ts:52:40)
        at Repository.findOneBy (/Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/repository/Repository.ts:539:44)
        at /Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/services/user.service.ts:78:37
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at /Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/services/user.service.ts:8:71
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (/Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/services/user.service.ts:4:12)
        at loginService (/Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/services/user.service.ts:75:110)
        at /Users/shravan/Documents/todolist/server/src/controllers/user.controller.ts:17:48

      109 |         };
      110 |     } catch (error) {
    > 111 |         console.error(error);
          |                 ^
      112 |         return {
      113 |             errors: [
      114 |                 {

      at src/services/user.service.ts:111:17
          at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
      at rejected (src/services/user.service.ts:6:65)

 FAIL  src/__tests__/user.test.ts
  POST /register
    ✓ should register user if all fields exist (44 ms)
    ✓ should throw error if email field is missing (11 ms)
    ✓ should throw error if email is invalid (3 ms)
    ✓ should throw error if name is empty (3 ms)
    ✓ should throw error if username is less than 4 characters (3 ms)
    ✓ should throw error if password is less than 8 characters (2 ms)
    ✕ should login a registered user (63 ms)

  ● POST /register › should login a registered user

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 200
    Received: 401

       97 |     it('should login a registered user', async () => {
       98 |         const loginResponse = await supertest(app).post('/api/users/login').send(registeredUser);
    >  99 |         expect(loginResponse.statusCode).toBe(200);
          |                                          ^
      100 |     });
      101 | });
      102 |

      at src/__tests__/user.test.ts:99:42
      at fulfilled (src/__tests__/user.test.ts:5:58)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 6 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.028 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: Any luck if you solve this? I am getting the same issue for few weeks already,  and part of the issue is with “eager” that my relation won’t able to auto load as well. If I test without “runInBand” from local, everything is working fine. With “runInBand” locally is not working, GitHub action failed not matter with that or not. 

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is whether the data source was initialized (`DataSource.isInitialized`).

I notice `UserRepository` uses `AppDataSource`. Assuming `testConnection` uses `TestDataSource`, you may instead provide 2 `DataSourceOptions` for `AppDataSource` and set the `NODE_ENV` environment variable to decide which option to apply.